# No connection to end device via switch

Tags: networking, switch

I have the switch D-Link DGS-105 at home and a very simple setup. In this switch there is a cable that goes to my router, one to an access point, one to my pc and one to my laptop.

But now I think my switch might be broken because I have no connection to my router anymore. I can't ping the router via my pc/laptop or with my phone connected to the access point.

After I unplugged the switch and plug it back in, everything went back to normal for 10min and the no connection again. Now doing this again wont help again. Strange thing is, that I don't have a connection my my laptop and pc but via the access point.

I did try to switch the ports and I saw that only the port where the router and the access point cable is connected the led of the switch is on. That is the same thing is still true when switching up all the ports. It's like the switch doesn't recognize the connection to my pc and laptop anymore. Means I can't ping the rounter via pc and laptop. Connecting the Pc/Laptop via access point or plugin in the router cable directly does work.

Any Idea what I could try to solve this?

What I have tryed:

- Trying differend ports with all connections
- Differend cables to the end devices
- Restarting the switch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make sure that the laptop and the PC have their network-card settings configured to auto-negotiate the speed and duplex settings.
(This should be the default setting anyway.)
Any other setting for speed and/or duplex will not work properly for this type of switch.

The other thing you can try is to remove all network cables AND the power from the switch and leave it totally disconnected for at least 10 minutes.
This will make sure that all internal memory in the switch is completely empty and when you re-connect it, it will really make a fresh start.
(Just restarting the switch will, in most cases, NOT clear the switch completely.)

If none of that helps then the switch is most likely broken and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Removing all the cables and the power cable for 10min+ did work. Now everything works like it should. I hope it will run stable now without getting this error again :)

Comment: @sirzento If that solved the issue your switch most likely suffered from a corrupt CAM table problem. This is a fairly rare thing, usually caused by a spike/fluctuation on the power-grid. High-end professional switches have internal protections against this, but consumer and SOHO stuff usually not. This may happen again, but you know how to fix it now. It it becomes a frequent occurrence consider replacing the switch with a different brand/model. A surge-protector (if you have one) may also help.

Comment: Since it consistently works with the router and access point and not the PC, I'd say there is probably some configuration or incompatibility issue rather than physical breakage. @Tonny messed-up CAM table will not cause the LED to turn off.

Comment: @user253751 CAM tables by itself will obviously not affect link-state LEDs, but I've seen a couple of cases were one thing led to another and the switch backplane started to act weird as a side-effect. One of the effects of a corrupt CAM table can be flooding the send/receive buffers on some (or all) ports with bogus traffic which can in turn cause those ports to "hang up". This a very low-end single-chip 5-port unmanaged switch. Not much resilience build in. Anything goes under such an error condition.